# Attempting to run a trivial Scalatest on a Spray Route

Tags: scala, spray, scalatest

Ultimately my goal is to write a custom Spray Directive for use by various routes in an existing application.  I have so far been unable to write a test for my new directive, so I simplified further until my custom code wasn't even in play.  I'm still not passing what I believe to be a trivial test.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import spray.http.StatusCodes
import spray.routing.{HttpService, Directives, Route}
import spray.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest

trait TrivialDirectivesTextFixture extends Directives {

  def trivialRoute: Route =
    path("test_route") {
      get { requestContext =>
        println("get")

        complete(StatusCodes.OK, "trivial response")
      }
    }

}

class TrivialDirectivesSpec extends FlatSpec with TrivialDirectivesTextFixture with ScalatestRouteTest with HttpService {

  def actorRefFactory = system

  "TrivialDirectives" should "trivially match" in {
    Get("/test_route") ~> sealRoute(trivialRoute) ~> check {
      println("check")

      assertResult(StatusCodes.OK) {
        println("status " + status)
        status
      }

      assertResult("trivial response") {
        println("response " + response)
        responseAs[String]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
get
check
[info] TrivialDirectivesSpec:
[info] TrivialDirectives
[info] - should trivially match *** FAILED ***
[info]   Request was neither completed nor rejected within 1 second (TrivialDirectivesSpec.scala:30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough point to write a comment

So I'll write it here, the problem is that

```
get { 
  complete("OK")
}
```

is translated to the code below, using some sort of implicit

```
get { ctx =>
  ctx.complete("OK")
}
```

thus when you do 
    get { ctx =>
      complete("OK")
    }

it is not translated properly

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing `complete()` to `requestContext.complete()`.  I don't really understand why, so I'd appreciate more comprehensive answers.

Comment: Or you just remove `requestContext =>`.